# Lightning debug mode still minifies my lwc code

Tags: lightning-web-components

Like the title says, i have enabled debug mode on my scratch org.
I get the "header interface" of the debug mode enabled but when i check my code on chromed dev tools, the code is still minified and showing variables as a and b etc...

Have you encountered this issue? Or know how to solve it?

for more context i've followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0B37nkNSVtg

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of the browser cache. Try:

1. Clear the cache for last 1 hr from chrome settings. If its still minified,
2. Logout and login again of the org

Comment: it worked, you are a god :)